# How to populate ComboBoxTool.ValueList with enum values?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, toolbar, infragistics

I am working on toolbar and I want to display `enum` with `ComboBoxTool` at a toolbar. The `ComboBoxTool` takes `ValueList` object. `Enum` needs to convert `ValueList` type.
How can I add `enum` to `ValueList`?
Thank for answers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgq5W.png)

Comment: Please show your effort to solve this first and tell us what specific problem you're running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the specified combo box with the members of the specified enumeration:

```cs
public void LoadEnumsIntoCombo(ComboBoxTool combo, Type type)
{
    Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(type);
    Infragistics.Win.ValueList valueList = new Infragistics.Win.ValueList();
    foreach(object value in enumValues)
    {                
        valueList.ValueListItems.Add(new ValueListItem(value, value.ToString()));
    }
    combo.ValueList = valueList;
}
```

And example of calling this method:

```cs
var comboBoxTool1 = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ComboBoxTool("ComboBoxTool1");
LoadEnumsIntoCombo(comboBoxTool1, typeof(ToolbarStyle));
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, how can i set default value to combobox? Do ypu have any idea?

Comment: Also how can i get value from  combobox, excuse me i am newbie for c#

Comment: @Ahmet Serdar: `ComboBoxTool.SelectedItem` returns the object behind the selected `ValueList` item.

Comment: Is there any way to set default value  to combobox?

Comment: @Ahmet Serdar: And to set the default value it is necessary to use the `SelectedItem` like: `comboBoxTool1.SelectedItem = comboBoxTool1.ValueList.FindByDataValue(put_here_your_enum_value);`

Comment: @Ahmet Serdar: Any further questions related to your post is welcome! :)

Comment: Furthermore:) My program is based on client server architecture. When client connect server, combobox will be active. I will attach image to question. How can i make visible like button? It should be transparent until connectde to server.

Comment: @Ahmet Serdar: It's seems different question. Please, create a new question, show what you did, and we'll try to help.